# has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. How do you debug?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am having problems with asp.net binding to a dropdownlist and I have no clue on how to debug. I checked out the other questions about this on stack but nothing has helped. As far as I can see the "name" it should select is in the list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ADataSource" DataTextField="Name" 
                                                    DataValueField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>'   Width="255" 
                                                    AppendDataBoundItems="true" TabIndex="3"  Font-Size="small"  EnableViewState="true"    >
                                             <asp:ListItem Text="Select"  Value="" />
                                           </asp:DropDownList>
```

Following is the error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
>         Message='dd1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
>       Parameter name: value
>         Source=System.Web
>         ParamName=value
>         StackTrace:
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   dataSource)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect()
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)
>              at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.DataBind()
>              at storeUpdate.GvStoresSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in line 233
>              at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleSelect(Int32 rowIndex)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>              at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>              at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>              at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>              at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>         InnerException:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value coming from `<%# Bind("Name") %>`, which is passed to the SelectedValue property, does not match an item in its collection.  Most likely causes:

- DropDownList has no items because the evaluation happens before the list gets bound
- The list is bound but is missing this particular value
- The value returned could be null

Comment: Is there away to see the value that it is trying to use?

Comment: Use `<%# Eval("Name") %>` outside of the control, and see what it loads.

Comment: @RamiZebian ensure that the value being bound exists in the list, or bind the selected value in the code-behind, rather than using <%# %> notation.

Answer (score 5):

DataBind stinks.  I tried all the suggestions mentioned and none of them worked.  Ended up setting `SelectedValue` to null, clearing all the items (`myDDL.Items.Clear()`), and then iterating through my list and manually adding new ListItems -  `myDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(myListEntry.Text,myListEntry.Value))`

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old thread, but Google brought this up as the first option for this problem - with a fairly generic search term.

Anyway, the problems I had with this and the way I solved it are as follows. The problem will either arise, like Brian Mains said for the following reasons :

> - DropDownList has no items because the evaluation happens before the    list gets bound
> - The list is bound but is missing this particular value
> - The value returned could be null

The problem i was experiencing, even though it wasn't very clear as i didn't get errors on some of the other DropDowns i was using the same method for, was that on load of the page, i was trying to use this code-behind to add an item to the DropDownList :

```
drpNationality.Text = GlobalScript.CountDatabaseRecords("SELECT [nationality_desc] FROM [tbl_people] INNER JOIN [tbl_lkup_nationality] AS nationality ON [nationality] = [nationality_id] WHERE [person_id] ='" + Session["ID"] + "'");
```

And here is the DropDown HTML (which had items populated by a DataSource) :

```
<label>Nationality:</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpNationality" runat="server" DataSourceID="Nationality_Datasource" DataTextField="nationality_desc" DataValueField="nationality_id">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now, the problem I was getting was that the data hadn't been bound to the control at the time of Load, when i was trying to add items in the code-behing. Because I was trying to pre-select a value from the database at start-up for the user (which did exist in the list), I wasn't too bothered if the item essentially appeared twice in there.

**So my work-around was the following.**

I changed the code behind to the following, so that the item was added to the DropDownList on execution of the Load Event code and then selected :

```
var = GlobalScript.CountDatabaseRecords("SELECT [nationality] FROM [tbl_people] INNER JOIN [tbl_lkup_nationality] AS nationality ON [nationality] = [nationality_id] WHERE [person_id] ='" + Session["ID"] + "'");
drpNationality.Items.Add(var);
drpNationality.Text = var;
```

But in order for the item which was chosen in the code-behind to stay once the page is fully loaded and not be overwritten by the DataSource, you must change the HTML to the following :

```
<label>Nationality:</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpNationality" runat="server" DataSourceID="Nationality_Datasource" DataTextField="nationality_desc" DataValueField="nationality_id" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now, when the page is loaded, the value from the database *should* be pre-selected in the drop down, and all the DataSource items should also be added.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is before setting the datasource and binding was clearing the dropdown.

```
private void ClearDropdown(DropDownList ddl)
{
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    ddl.SelectedValue = null;
    ddl.Text = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Here is what was going on.  I had originally set the value to something that wasn't in my drop down list.  If what you had originally isn't among the values you want to display on the drop down list then it won't work. For example if you originally had Fred in the data, you need to have Fred in that drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

If the dropdown controls `Text` property is assigned with any value before assigning the datasource, this error will occur.

Example:

```
StatusDropDown.Text = "some value";
StatusDropDown.DataSource = statusDatatable;
```

While executing the 2nd line, you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the method for clearing the dropdown list was initially set as `ddlname.text = string.empty`.

I reset it to `ddlname.items.clear()` and this resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem - the basic issue was the format of the underlying SQL database field referenced by my RadioButtonList.  I converted the DB field from NCHAR to VARCHAR ... I think NCHAR adds additional content to the field which threw an error on evaluation by the RadiolButton.  You may have to drop and load data that was put in as NCHAR to VARCHAR.  This worked for me .. hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are setting the value of the dropdown before databinding it with a value that is not in the data bound list.

In my case this occurred like I set the value of dropdown with `"ABC"` and the list I was binding with dropdown has got only values `{"1", "2", "3" ,"4"}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue adding the blow extra code before binding my datasource:

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, "");
ddl.SelectedValue = "";
ddl.DataSource = null;
ddl.DataBind();
```

As dropdownlist was getting a selected value(for whatever reason), i tried to insert a new value(here an *empty string*) and set it as selected one , then *null* value binding to refresh the datasource.It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after researching almost a week I found a beautiful solution.

**Problem:** the error occurs when you want to setup a Dropdownlist inside `<EditItemTemplate>` encountering an issue where a SelectedValue property in your code is set to a value that doesn't exist in the list of items.

Let me provide a scenario to illustrate my solution. Suppose you have two tables named Customer and Category. I'm setting up a dropdown list for a column called Category_Id in the Customer table, but the list items of my Dropdown (Column name:Category) are stored in the Category table.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomer" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCategoryList" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" AppendDataBoundItems="True" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Category_Id") %>' CssClass="form-select form-select-sm w-auto"></asp:DropDownList>
```

You need to create a DataSource specifically for this dropdown to generate the list of items before a value is selected, thereby preventing errors from occurring.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCategoryList" runat="server" TypeName="EF_StaffWeb.BLL.CategoryBL" SelectMethod="CategoryList" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

All you need to have just create a method in your BL as bellow:

```
public IEnumerable<QueryPanelCategory> All()
{
    return _repository.All.ToList();
}

[System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
public List<StringString> CategoryList()
{
    var _returnList = new List<StringString>();
    _returnList = All().Select(d => new StringString() { Text = d.Category, Value = d.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
    return _returnList;
}
```

This solution is tested by me in multiple places and works brilliant.