# asp.net dropdownlist doesn't accept text after databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dorpdownlists in my page. One is databound, and another has values added at the design time.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="maritalStatus" runat="server" Width="180px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--SELECT--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Widow(er)</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" Width="180px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This is my Codebehind for filling the country dropDownList

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT CountryID,  CountryName FROM Country", con))
{
      SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
      DataTable countryTab = new DataTable("Country");
      dad.Fill(countryTab);
      country.DataSource = countryTab;
      country.DataTextField = "CountryName";
      country.DataValueField = "CountryID";
      country.DataBind();
      country.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", "-1"));

}
```

But when I set "--SELECT--" to both dropDownLists, the maritalStatus dropDownList works fine; But, country dropdown shows this error

> "'country' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items"

```
maritalStatus.Text = "--SELECT--";
country.Text = "--SELECT--";
```

If I set country Text as "-1", It will work fine. I don't understand why both dropDownLists are behaving in different way.

Comment: Did you look at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654220/has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-list-of-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is there is no Value like `--SELECT--` in your dropdown therefore their is no match in the `ListItem` collection and hence the exception.

According to documentation of Dropdownlist [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property it:-

> Gets or sets the SelectedValue property of the ListControl control.

Thus, when you are saying `country.Text = "--SELECT--";`, it is searching for a value of `--SELECT--` which is not present in the collection but when you search for `-1` it finds it and there is no exception.

Coming to the behavior difference in two dropdowns, it doesn't matter whether you bind it `programmatically` or `declaratively` both will behave the same and you will get the exception in both case.

Comment: Thanks :)  I didn't get the exception for the first one. But it was not working. Now fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace

```
country.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", "-1"));
```

to

```
country.Items.Insert("0","--SELECT--");
```

this will solve issue

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
country.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", "-1"));
```

To

```
country.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--SELECT--", "0"));
```