# Why does my DropDownList not populate with Items from the Page_Load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this control to fetch some data:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="newsOrEvent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("newsEvent") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in my Page_Load I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            newsOrEvent.Items.clear();
            newsOrEvent.Items.Add("News");
            newsOrEvent.Items.Add("Event");

                    if (!this.IsPostBack)
                    {
                        if(newsID != 0) 
                        {
                            this.BindRepeater();
                           // this.BindImageRepeater();

                        }   

                    }


        }
```

My compiler is saying:  The name 'newsOrEvent' does not exist in the current context

```
private void BindRepeater()
        {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                string myQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblNewsEvents WHERE newsID = {0}", newsID);


                     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, con))
                     {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            news.DataSource = dt;
                            news.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This SO article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654220/has-a-selectedvalue-which-is-invalid-because-it-does-not-exist-in-the-list-of-it) suggested:

- I should `.clear` the items first
- Enter the `<%# Eval("newsEvent") %>` by itself to see if it loads in the page, which it does.

It also said:

> If the dropdown controls Text property is assigned with any value before assigning the datasource, this error will occur.

How can I add the items first, before it reads the Eval?

I can not see why a `DropDownList` does not populate.

Comment: Show the page load method. Also maybe just clean and rebuild, even restart, especially if you add another server control and cannot access that one from code behind either.

Comment: @Crowcoder posted - as in, start over?

Comment: no restart your machine to clear out IIS Express.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have done that, no change though :(

Comment: If you add other controls can you reference them from code behind?

Comment: @Crowcoder Nope, exact same message ...

Comment: I had a feeling. So the problem is not databinding or dropdown specific. You might consider changing your question title or asking a new question.

Comment: 1. `asp:DropDownList` control doesn't have `Text` property. 2. where parameter `newsID` comes from?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments `asp:DropDownList` control doesn't have `Text` property. The easiest way to get your dropdown filled is to fill it **declaratively**. Something like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewsOrEvents" runat="server" DataTextField="NewsTitle"
    DataValueField="newsID" 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="sqlNews">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="News"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Event"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlNews" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionFromWebConfig %>"
    SelectCommand="select newsID, newsTitle from dbo.tblNewsEvents where newsId=@newsID">
    <SelectParameters>
         <%--if newsID comes from some control --%>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="someControl" PropertyName="someProperty" Name="newsID" Type="Int32" />
        <%--if newsId comes from querystring --%>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="newsid" Name="newsID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

No code behind required. Just follow KISS principle (**K**eep **I**t **S**imple **S**tupid)

**Follow Up**
`SelectedValue` (`Text`) property of `DropdownList` control can be set only after the control is **`DataBound`**. It means that you can set `SelectedValue='<%#Eval("dataField")%>'` only if it is in a binding container and `DropDownList` itself has `DataSourceID`. Else you have to set `.SelectedValue` after `DataBound` event.

Comment: Yes it does have [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) because it inherits `ListControl`.

Comment: Sorry, `Text` property really exists (inherited) and, for dropdown is the same as `SelectedValue`.